# Inserting a sequenced value into a new table ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I can't figure out how to insert data into a new table from a record that has a sequence from a different table. Specifically, I have a table called `customers_f` and I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
 INSERT INTO customers_f(billing_account_num)
 VALUES(billing_account_num.CURRVAL);
```

This is not working seeing as the sequence pertains to the bill_tos_f table. How can I manage to have the `billing_account_num` value from the `bill_tos_f` put into my 'customers_f' table?

Below I've posted the info from bill_tos_f including the table itself, the sequence dealing with `billing_account_num`, and the insert from `bill_tos_f`.  Thanks in advance!

```
 CREATE TABLE bill_tos_f
(
  billing_account_num NUMBER(5)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_to_num_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  bill_to_first_name VARCHAR2(25)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_first_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_middle_name VARCHAR2(25),
  bill_to_last_name VARCHAR2(25)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_last_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_street VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_street_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_city VARCHAR2(30)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_city_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_state CHAR(2)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_state_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_zip CHAR(5)
    CONSTRAINT bill_tos_f_bill_zip_nn NOT NULL,
  bill_to_country CHAR(3)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 52315
MAXVALUE 99999
NOCYCLE
NOCACHE;

INSERT INTO bill_tos_f(billing_account_num, bill_to_first_name,  bill_to_middle_name, bill_to_last_name, bill_to_street, bill_to_city, bill_to_state, bill_to_zip, bill_to_country)
VALUES(bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.NEXTVAL, 'mike', 'row', 'smith', '983 Circle Point', 'Atlanta', 'GA', '3825', 'USA');
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? what is it? If not, what result you are getting? BTW, sequences, unlike triggers, `do NOT` pertain to tables. They are standalone objects

Comment: @Hawk it's saying the sequence does not exist when it does

Comment: Have you created a sequence `billing_account_num` ?

Comment: BTW, if you think `billing_account_num` column in `bill_tos_f` table is a sequence, then that is wrong. If you want to insert based on that column, you need to use the sequence name `INSERT INTO customers_f(billing_account_num)
  VALUES(bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.NEXTVAL);`

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle sequences are not tied to columns, they are independent objects. The following SQL statement should work for you.

```
INSERT INTO customers_f(billing_account_num)
  VALUES(bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.CURRVAL);
```

However, it would be better if you could use a PLSQL block instead.

```
DECLARE
   v_seqval NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_seqval := bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.NEXTVAL;

  INSERT INTO bill_tos_f(billing_account_num, bill_to_first_name, bill_to_middle_name, bill_to_last_name, bill_to_street, bill_to_city, bill_to_state, bill_to_zip, bill_to_country)
  VALUES(v_seqval, 'mike', 'row', 'smith', '983 Circle Point', 'Atlanta', 'GA', '3825', 'USA');

  INSERT INTO customers_f(billing_account_num)
  VALUES(v_seqval);

END;
```

Comment: `bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.CURRVAL` will not work, unless `bill_tos_f_bill_acc_num_seq.NEXTVAL` is run previously in the same session